# Could not restore Flink keyed state backend from savepoint when upgrading from 1.10 to 1.11

Tags: migration, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We tried to migrate to Flink 1.11 recovering the job from a savepoint taken in 1.10. The job code was not changed, only updated the Flink version of the dependencies to 1.11 (in SBT, we use Scala) and re-built the jar.
All operators have uids and the job correctly recovers from that savepoint if run on a 1.10 cluster, we are getting the following exception and have no clue:

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception while creating StreamOperatorStateContext.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:204)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:247)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(OperatorChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$beforeInvoke$0(StreamTask.java:473)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:47)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.beforeInvoke(StreamTask.java:469)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:522)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:721)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:546)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not restore keyed state backend for CoStreamFlatMap_8a6da66867c6cf8469bae55e9f834297_(1/1) from any of the 1 provided restore options.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:135)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.keyedStatedBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:317)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:144)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.state.BackendBuildingException: Failed when trying to restore heap backend
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackendBuilder.build(HeapKeyedStateBackendBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsStateBackend.createKeyedStateBackend(FsStateBackend.java:540)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.lambda$keyedStatedBackend$1(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:301)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:121)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing value for the key 'org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.savepoint.Savepoint'
    at org.apache.flink.util.LinkedOptionalMap.unwrapOptionals(LinkedOptionalMap.java:190)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializerSnapshot.restoreSerializer(KryoSerializerSnapshot.java:86)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:546)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:505)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.snapshotsToRestoreSerializers(NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.java:225)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.getRestoredNestedSerializers(NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.CompositeTypeSerializerSnapshot.restoreSerializer(CompositeTypeSerializerSnapshot.java:204)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.StateSerializerProvider.previousSchemaSerializer(StateSerializerProvider.java:189)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.StateSerializerProvider.currentSchemaSerializer(StateSerializerProvider.java:164)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.RegisteredKeyValueStateBackendMetaInfo.getStateSerializer(RegisteredKeyValueStateBackendMetaInfo.java:136)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.StateTable.getStateSerializer(StateTable.java:315)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.CopyOnWriteStateTable.createStateMap(CopyOnWriteStateTable.java:54)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.CopyOnWriteStateTable.createStateMap(CopyOnWriteStateTable.java:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.StateTable.<init>(StateTable.java:98)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.CopyOnWriteStateTable.<init>(CopyOnWriteStateTable.java:49)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.AsyncSnapshotStrategySynchronicityBehavior.newStateTable(AsyncSnapshotStrategySynchronicityBehavior.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapSnapshotStrategy.newStateTable(HeapSnapshotStrategy.java:243)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapRestoreOperation.createOrCheckStateForMetaInfo(HeapRestoreOperation.java:185)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapRestoreOperation.restore(HeapRestoreOperation.java:152)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackendBuilder.build(HeapKeyedStateBackendBuilder.java:114)
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The savepoint comes from a savepoint processed with the stateprocessor API and the state in the `KeyedStateBootstrapFunction` is made of:

```
  var mapToDetector: MapState[String, Map[String, Detector]] = null
  var detectorsConfigs: MapState[String,AnomalyStepConfiguration] = null
  var outputTopic : ValueState[String]= null
  var pipeStatus: MapState[String, String] = null
  var debounceMap: MapState[String, Map[String, DebounceStats]] = null
```

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.savepoint.Savepoint` is renamed in [FLINK-16247](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-16247). However, this class is used in savepoint metadata and should not exist in keyed state serializer on task side. In other words, did you use something related to checkpoint or savepoint on task side in state access?

I also try to use [StateMachineExample](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/release-1.10/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/statemachine) to create savepoint in Flink-1.10.2 and it resumes successfully within Flink-1.11.1 cluster. The program also used `CopyOnWriteStateTable` by default which is what you see in your exception stack trace.

Comment: Thanks Yun, actually we tried with 1.11.0. So you mean we are storing something Savepoint classes related in the state? Nothing i am aware of....

Comment: Have you ever register something when using kryo? What's your type of state descriptor?

Comment: Hi Yun, Kryo is being used as the classes are not POJO or Avro. I've updated my question with relevant info.